# It is not possible to unset IFS in ksh93. Is it documented?

Tags: ksh

In ksh93 it is possible to unset any variable like so:

```
$ var=value; echo "$<${var+set}"
<set>

$ unset var; echo "<${var+set}>"
<>
```

However, `IFS` doesn't work the same way:

```
$ unset IFS; echo "<${IFS+set}>"
set
```

This did not happen in any other shell I tested. It may be a bug, but seems deliberate to me.

However, I can not find where is it documented (if it is).

Also, using `:+` only extends the expansion to null values:

```
$ var="value"; echo "<${var:+set}> <${var+set}>"
<set> <set>

$ var=""     ; echo "<${var:+set}> <${var+set}>"
<> <set>

$ unset var  ; echo "<${var:+set}> <${var+set}>"
<> <>
```

That is not the problem.

Is only related to IFS:

```
IFS="value"; echo "<${IFS:+set}> <${IFS+set}>"
<set> <set>

IFS=""     ; echo "<${IFS:+set}> <${IFS+set}>"
<> <set>

unset IFS  ; echo "<${IFS:+set}> <${IFS+set}>"
<> <set>                    <------------------- should be <> <>
```

Version info:

```
ksh -c 'echo "$KSH_VERSION"'
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this in `version         sh (AT&T Research) 2020.0.0`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks, that helps.

Comment: @Isaac: http://www.kornshell.com points to https://github.com/att/ast and `git log --grep=IFS` finds a commit that contains `05-02-01 3d.sh: IFS may be unset and { ash bsh } don't on startup -- wow`

Comment: This commit might have nothing to do with it but there is another interesting commit on `2020.0.0` branch: `13-06-20  A bug in which  ${IFS+abc} did not expand to abc when IFS is unset has been fixed.`

Comment: In line with what `${IFS+set}` does, `typeset -p IFS` shows `IFS=''` after `unset IFS`. But word splitting still happens after the `unset`, unlike after explicitly setting `IFS=""`.